# BlueZ with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth, raspbian-jessie, bluez

I'm working on a project that involves interfacing a PC (windows based) with a raspberry pi 3 using Bluetooth with c++. I've done some research and found that the library BlueZ is one of the best options for successfully connecting both devices. My question is do I need to download and install BlueZ? or it comes with the latest version of Raspian? If I need to install it do you know how I could do it?

Comment: If you REALLY are using Jessie you are out of luck - it is obsolete. You should take the See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works and read 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And one criteria in StackExchange is to do research before asking! I will vote to close this as it show no sign of research!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, BlueZ is included in the latest versions of Raspberry Pi OS. To check that it is running on your system, use the command `service bluetooth status`.

BlueZ's API for interfacing with various languages are documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

There is the the mgmt API for system level tasks and the D-Bus API for application level tasks.

There is a command line tool called `bluetoothctl` that can be useful for exploring the capabilities of the various D-Bus API's. `btmgmt` does the same for the mgmt API.
Typing `help` in either of these tools will give you a list of the commands.

There are examples of how to do various tasks with BlueZ available in the source tree at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test